# Display text file contents in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, text-files, bufferedreader

I need to pull my text file contents into a jtable and display them. I have tried all sorts of code and it hangs and errors out. I think it keeps repeating the table values over and over, but I don't understand why this is happening because I call the reader.close() command and the reader isn't supposed to go on if there is not a next line.

Here is the DefaultTableModel code:

```
    String columns[] =  {  "Name", "Age", "Email Address", "Cell Number"  };
    JTable contactTable = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel tableModel;

    // table with 4 columns
    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0,4);
    tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
    contactTable.setModel(tableModel);
```

Here is the reading from text file code:

```
    void showContacts(){
    String line;
    BufferedReader reader;


    try{       
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)) //this gives me an error???
        {
           tableModel.addRow(line.split(", ")); //this has a comma and a space bc that                        is how the file is written to
        }
        reader.close();
     }
    catch(IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Buffered Reader issue.");
    }

}
```

Here is the text file contents:

```
    Name, Age, Email Address, Cell Number, 
    John Smith, 21, jsmith@site.com, 1234564789,
```

Comment: What is `file`? If file not found at sepcified location then it will throw FileNotFound Exception.

Comment: You need to do some debugging first! Put in error code or use a debugger. Your catch block is terrible as it will tell you nothing of use. At least print out the stacktrace: `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The while statement gives me an "illegal start of expression" error. From what I can tell, this is the standard while statement to read lines from a file.

Comment: Oh man. don't you see an extra closing paranthesis?

Comment: the file is fine. i can write to it from a different method.

Comment: @asgs I think } is for the class to end ;)

Comment: O my soul! Thank you asgs! LOL. I had been staring at it for toooo long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line :

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null))
```

to

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
```